# как сделать крутящийся кружочек загрузки когда форму отсылаешь показывает что форма в процессе отправки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

как сделать крутящийся кружочек загрузки когда форму отсылаешь показывает что форма в процессе отправки?

чтобы на кнопке появлялась и крутилась а когда отправилась перестала крутится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим так

```js
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('#send').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.load').style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
.load {
  display: none;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  animation: Rotate .3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes Rotate {
  from {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
  <div class="load"></div>
</form>
```